# Oracle VPD vs Pluggables for security

Tags: oracle

A member of the team believes that using Oracle Virtual Private Database to control data access in one giant database is secure.

They feel that VPD gives fine grain controls so different apps can use the same database.

I say that a 19c pluggable database with TNS restricted IPs and user roles is a better option.

I've never worked with VPD.

Which is the more secure solution?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, just using separate *schemas* within a single database instance (or PDB) is often sufficient to separate different apps. It is equally secure and requires fewer system resources, but it will depend on your application's specific requirements:

- If there are any availability/dependency issues between the apps at the database level, it makes sense to keep them in the same instance, for example.
- There's no reason you can't use separate service names and use features like Connection Manager (if you have Enterprise Edition) to still provide network-level isolation of apps.
- VPD really only makes sense if your applications are *sharing* the same tables in the same schemas, but not the same *data* in those tables, or if some data needs to be restricted by *user*. If not, it doesn't really apply.
- For VPD to work best, it often requires applications to make calls to DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO and like packages to set session variables used by VPD to know which rows to display or protect. Compatibility of your application code with VPD may also be a factor.